# Shorter code for capitalize function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I solved this problem here https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/capitalize

Description:
You are given a string . Your task is to capitalize each word of it. In a word only the first character is capitalized. Example 12abc when capitalized remains 12abc - because of this 'title' doesn't work properly with string like '1 w 2 r 3g'.
I need to check combinations of digits and lowcase letters. This is my code:

```
def capitalize(string):
    result = list (string.title())
    for index in range (len (string)-1):
      if string[index].isdigit () and string[index+1].islower ():
        result[index+1] = result[index+1].lower()
    result = ''.join([char for char in result])
    return (result)
```

But this code is too cumbersome. Can somebody help with a more elegant pythonic decision? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `re` module can help here:

```
titlesub = re.compile(r'\b[a-zA-Z]').sub  # Precompile regex and prebind method for efficiency  
def capitalize(string):
    return titlesub(lambda x: x.group(0).upper(), string)
```

Note: `\b` handles word/non-word character boundaries (word characters are alphanumeric and underscore), so it will prevent `12abc` from capitalizing `a`, but it won't do so for `"abc` (which becomes `"Abc`).

While `\b` is convenient, it does mean strings like `"won't"` will be capitalized a `"Won'T"`. If that's an issue, a more targeted selector can be used to capitalize when not preceded by a non-space character:

```
titlesub = re.compile(r'(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z]').sub
```

Comment: Ah forgot about word boundaries! Yes I think this will work for a lot more cases!

Comment: In the following sentence `'once they're created they can't be changed.'`, could be that output correct `Once They'Re Created They Can'T Be Changed.` ?

Comment: @J.Piquard: Yar, the whole problem is tricky. Using a negative look-behind to exclude non-space characters might work better for the definition of "word": `titlesub = re.compile(r'(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z]').sub`

Answer (score 2):

```
' '.join([x.capitalize() for x in s.split(' ')])
```

Comment: Note: Won't handle non-space whitespace (e.g. tabs).

Comment: agreed. your answer is preferred.

Comment: I Tried both method using _regular expression_ and _list comprehension_ using join and they **both** score a 20/20. Because it is said on the exercice than 
- The string consists of alphanumeric characters and spaces.

So there is no need to handle special characters like `\t` `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `re` module

```
import re

someStr = '1 w 2 r 3ga hello world'
re.sub(r"(?<=[0-9])[a-zA-Z]", lambda m: m.group(0).lower(), someStr.title())
```

outputs:

```
# 1 W 2 R 3ga Hello World
```

The [positive look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<=[0-9])` only matches alpha characters (`[a-zA-Z]`) which have a number infront of them. With these matches, we use the `.lower()` method to 'undo' the effects of `.title()`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate solution without using the `re` module.

```
def capitalize(string):
    result = []
    for word in string.split():
        result.append(word[0].upper() + word[1:].lower())
    return (' '.join(result))
```

Comment: If there are two (or more) consecutive spaces, the result won't be relevant, we shall keep all spaces. With input  '1 w 2 r   3g' its output is '1 W 2 R 3g', lost two spaces.

Comment: Humm, in the case of your sample `'1 w 2 r 3g'`, I get the same string length with `'1 W 2 R 3g'` (10 letters before and after).

Comment: Right you are. There just were other test cases including multiple spaces.

Comment: Did you see my question about the @ShadowRanger answer ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with regular expression yet, it's on my to-do list)